# parsing HTML using beautifulSoup with child and parent div having same class

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have this HTML from which I have to extract data:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="main">
  <div class="utlimate"><p>hello</p></div>
  <div class = "headline"><p>some text</p></div>
   <div class="content">
     <div class = "utimate"> <p>TOP</p>
        <div class ="utlimate"> <p>data1</p></div>
        <div class ="utlimate"> <p>it could be anything</p></div>
        <div class ="utlimate"> <p>not</p></div>
        <div class ="utlimate"> <p></p></div>

     </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to access `<div class="ultimate">` with `<p>` that has value "data1", "it could be anything", "not".The code I tried for this :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML_data)     #HTML_data is all html content
first_div = soup.find('div',{"class" : "content"})
second_div = first_div.find('div',{"class" : "utlimate"})
div_list = second_div.findall('div',{"class" : "utlimate"})
```

I got error in my code last line **'NoneType' object is not callable**

How do i access only those div's???plz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML_data)     #HTML_data is all html content
first_div = soup.find('div',{"class" : "content"})
second_div = first_div.find('div',{"class" : "utimate"})
div_list = second_div.findAll('div',{"class" : "utlimate"})
```

The method for getting the list is `findAll`, not `findall`.
There's no "ultimate" in the HTML fragment, they're "utlimate" or "utimate". Are those typos?

Answer (score 1):

Is Soup None?

I suggest you re-factor your code to guard against this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML_data)     #HTML_data is all html content
if soup ==None:
    //Error
else:
    c = soup.contents
    // Use RE here
```